# SCEditor emoticon from BBcode not convert to html

Tags: bbcode, emoticons, sceditor

I created [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) by this code

```
var textBBcode = null;
$(function () {
    textBBcode = $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: "bbcode",
        style: "js/api/sceditor/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css",
        emoticonsRoot: "js/api/sceditor/"
    });
});
```

And get the value(BBCode) and convert to html by this code

```
var val = textBBcode.sceditor('instance').val();
var result = textBBcode.sceditor('instance').fromBBCode(val, true);
```

The result is nearly OK, except the emoticon. It's doesn't convert.

How to fix that?

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: have you fixed it? having the same issue..maybe external js icon parser?